# Using Python win32com to get list of Excel worksheets

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Looking for a simple way to get a list of the worksheets in an Excel workbook using win32com in Python 3. I would prefer to avoid iterating, but can't find a function to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- Callig the [`.Sheets`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.sheets) property of the workbook, returns a [Sheets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets) collection, `<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.Sheets instance at 0x1597583762504>`

  - In order to get each sheet, **you must iterate**, which returns an object, `<win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library._Worksheet instance at 0x1597583219080>` for each sheet.
  - To get the name of each sheet, you must use the `.Name` method
- As shown below, you can easily get `sheet_names` with a list comprehension
- Alternative, you can get a dictionary of worksheet objects with

  - `ws = {f'ws{i}': wb.Sheets(sheet.Name) for i, sheet in enumerate(wb.Sheets)}`
  - Assign a value with `ws['ws0'].Range('A1').Value = 1`

### Function

```py
import win32com.client as win32
from pathlib import Path
import sys

win32c = win32.constants

def run_excel(f_path: Path, f_name: str) -> list:

    filename = f_path / f_name

    # create excel object
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')

    # excel can be visible or not
    excel.Visible = True  # False
    
    # try except for file / path
    try:
        wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
    except com_error as e:
        if e.excepinfo[5] == -2146827284:
            print(f'Failed to open spreadsheet.  Invalid filename or location: {filename}')
        else:
            raise e
        sys.exit(1)

    # get worksheet names        
    sheet_names = [sheet.Name for sheet in wb.Sheets]
        
    wb.Close(True)
    excel.Quit()
        
    return sheet_names
```

### Setup and function call

```
# file path
f_path = Path.cwd()  # file in current working directory
# f_path = Path(r'c:\...\Documents')  # file located somewhere else

# excel file
f_name = 'test.xlsx'

# function call
run_excel(f_path, f_name)

# output
['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3', 'Sheet4']

# create a worksheet object
ws1 = wb.Sheets('Sheet1')
```

- [How to create a pivot table in Excel with python win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509367/how-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-excel-with-python-win32com)
- [Automate Excel with Python](https://github.com/trenton3983/Excel_Automation_with_Python)

  - Examples with Pivot Table
- [Excel VBA reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/overview/excel)
- [Workbook object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook)
- [Worksheet object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet)