# How to highlight rows based on content in Excel Dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I have an excel file containing data like the one to left, and I'm trying to format it to get
the data formatting as table to the right.

[image]

With my current code I'm able to format all rows containig headers (H1, H2,...)

This is the content of file.xlsx:

This is my current code:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

data = {'H1': {0: 'A', 1: '', 2: 'H1', 3: 'A', 4: '', 5: 'H1', 6: 'A', 7: 'A', 8: 'B', 9: 'B', 10: 'B', 11: '', 12: 'H1', 13: 'B', 14: 'B', 15: '', 16: 'H1', 17: 'C', 18: 'C', 19: 'C', 20: 'D', 21: 'D', 22: ''}, 'H2': {0: 'Rty', 1: '', 2: 'H2', 3: 'Rty', 4: '', 5: 'H2', 6: 'Rty', 7: 'Rty', 8: 'Rty', 9: 'Rty', 10: 'Rty', 11: '', 12: 'H2', 13: 'Rty', 14: 'Rty', 15: '', 16: 'H2', 17: 'Rty', 18: 'Rty', 19: 'Rty', 20: 'Rty', 21: 'Rty', 22: ''}, 'H3': {0: '1195', 1: '', 2: 'H3', 3: '1195', 4: '', 5: 'H3', 6: '1195', 7: '1195', 8: '1195', 9: '1195', 10: '1195', 11: '', 12: 'H3', 13: '1195', 14: '1195', 15: '', 16: 'H3', 17: '1195', 18: '1195', 19: '1195', 20: '1195', 21: '1195', 22: ''}, 'H4': {0: '9038', 1: 'H3=9038, 000', 2: 'H4', 3: '1355', 4: 'H3=1355, 363', 5: 'H4', 6: '2022', 7: '2022', 8: '2022', 9: '2022', 10: '2022', 11: 'H3=2022, 234', 12: 'H4', 13: '2564', 14: '2564', 15: 'H3=2564, 726', 16: 'H4', 17: '1501', 18: '1501', 19: '1501', 20: '1501', 21: '1501', 22: 'H3=1501, 143'}, 'H5': {0: '1537', 1: '', 2: 'H5', 3: '8', 4: '', 5: 'H5', 6: '59', 7: '78', 8: '76', 9: '6', 10: '31', 11: '', 12: 'H5', 13: '71', 14: '17', 15: '', 16: 'H5', 17: '72', 18: '89', 19: '47', 20: '32', 21: '233', 22: ''}}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Output')

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Output']
number_rows = len(df.index)

format1 = workbook.add_format({'bg_color': 'black', 'font_color': 'yellow'})

for r in range(0,number_rows):
    if df.iat[r,0] == "H1":
        worksheet.set_row(r+1, None, format1) 

writer.save()
```

This is my current output:

[image]

I'm stuck in how to limit the format from column A to E and in how to intarcalate color green, yellow, green yello depending
when values in column A changes. I mean, for all consecutive values in column A = "A" highlight in green, when changes highlight to yellow
when changes highlightto green again and so on.

How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: First, I suggest using the python `win32com` module to control Excel and then the best way to figure out how to automate Excel, is to record a VBA macro in Excel of what you want, this will "mostly" give you an idea of the methods to use in python. See [How to create a pivot table in Excel with python win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509367) as an example.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Do you mean, do a VBA macro that works for what I want. Then replicate the same steps/commands in python using win32com?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. There's a Jupyter notebook link in that answer I linked to. It has examples

Comment: Thanks so much Trenton, I'll check the links your shared. One last question. My actual data is in a list and then I use Pandas Dataframe and `StyleFrame.ExcelWriter` to save it in an excel file. Using win32com would I be able to take that input from a python list, apply the "VBA macro" through win32com commands and save it in an excel file? or do I need to save the file and once I have output.xlsx, take that Excel file and modify its content with win32com?

Comment: _apply the VBA macro_ using win32com, you aren't applying the Excel macro. win32com exposes all of the Excel methods. You then write python code using those methods. The benefit of win32com is all possible methods are exposed. Most of the python modules do not seem to have access to all the functionality of Excel. Recording a macro will just tell you which method to use for specific functionality.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it with different excel library, like openpyxl

You can format each cell separately
For example:

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Font, Color, colors, fills
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for r in dataframe_to_rows(df, index=False, header=True):
    ws.append(r)

a1 = ws['A1']
a1.font = Font(color="FF0000")
a1.fill = fills.PatternFill(patternType='solid', fgColor=Color(rgb='00FF00'))
wb.save("pandas_openpyxl.xlsx")
```

They have great documentation here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I still figuring out how to get my goal, but your option it seems to have another good approach and I was able to highlight at least the rows containg "H1,H2.." in an easiest way than with my previous attempt.

Comment: Thanks so much, with your example and the link your share and after several testings, I was able to get my desired result using the library openpyxl you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to continue using the `xlsxwriter` Python module you may use the `write(…)` method on the worksheet object to set the contents and formatting of a cell in one step.

You will have to break up your `to_excel()` method and write each DataFrame value individually in a loop.

Example cell creation and formatting call:

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'italic': True})

# inside a loop iterating over your DataFrame
worksheet.write(row, column, value, cell_format)  # Cell is bold and italic.
```

Comment: Thanks JimmyNJ for your other approach. I know that how I want to format the sheet content is kind of complex, but for example, how would you format all rows having "A" in first column?

Comment: @GerCas : You'll have to iterate over cell values and compare the first character to 'A' and then you can call write(...) again.