# Highlighting rows based on a condition

Tags: pandas, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter, pandas-styles

I have this random dataframe containing two columns with dates, I've been trying to highlight rows where the start date exists inside a list of condition dates. Here goes my failed attempt:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({"Start": pd.date_range("1-jan-2021", periods=10, freq="1H")}).assign(**{"End": lambda d: d["Start"]+pd.Timedelta(hours=20)})

date_condition = ['2021-01-01 05:00:00','2021-01-01 08:00:00', '2021-01-01 02:00:00']
df = df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color : yellow' if x['Start'] in date_condition)
```

Since I'm trying to export this dataframe using xlswriter, I'm looking for a method to keep the background color even in the excel file. Thank you !

Comment: There is no way to apply pandas display options to excel formatting. These are totally separate things, and there's no mechanism for applying formatting, including highlighting, in the `pd.DataFrame.to_excel` method. Instead, I'd first check out [options for applying formatting manually to excel workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63074667/3888719), since that will be the hard part.

Comment: That is untrue. The pandas styler has a to excel function [`pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html) which can export pandas styles to excel.

Comment: omg. my bad! thanks @HenryEcker!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can use a combination of [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
date_condition = ['2021-01-01 05:00:00', '2021-01-01 08:00:00',
                  '2021-01-01 02:00:00']

highlighted_rows = np.where(df['Start'].isin(date_condition),
                            'background-color: yellow',
                            '')
# Apply calculated styles to each column:
styler = df.style.apply(lambda _: highlighted_rows)
styler.to_excel('output.xlsx')  # use styler to export to excel
# styler  # to display in NoteBook
```

Or with `isin` + [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
date_condition = ['2021-01-01 05:00:00', '2021-01-01 08:00:00',
                  '2021-01-01 02:00:00']

highlighted_rows = df['Start'].isin(date_condition).map({
    True: 'background-color: yellow',
    False: ''
})
# Apply calculated styles to each column:
styler = df.style.apply(lambda _: highlighted_rows)
styler.to_excel('output.xlsx')  # use styler to export to excel
# styler  # to display in NoteBook
```

---

In Excel:

[image: styled spreadsheet]

In Jupyter Notebook

[image: styled table]