# Adding color by string to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-styles

I'm working on a dataframe that I output to an html file. I would like to add colors to certain strings:

```
df1 = df1[(
    df1['Visitor'].str.contains('^TOR|^MTL|^CGY|^WPG|^VAN|^EDM|^OTT', na=False)
) | (df1['Home'].str.contains('^TOR|^MTL|^CGY|^WPG|^VAN|^EDM|^OTT', na=False))]

df1.fillna('', inplace=True)
df1.to_html('schedule.html', index=False)
```

The above code removes all rows that don't contain any of the listed teams. I would like to add colors to the rows that are left by string. for example `'TOR'` would be colored blue.

As seen in another thread, this is what I tried but nothing changed:

```
    def styler(col):
  
    if col.name != 'Visitor vs Home':
        return [''] * len(col)

    bg_color = col.map({
        'TOR': 'blue',
        'MTL': 'red',
        'VAN': 'green',
    }).fillna('')  
    return 'background-color:' + bg_color


df1.style.apply(styler)
```

Any tips or suggestions are very much welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried and what were your results?

Comment: added what I have tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) can *only* be used for *exact* string matching. If needing to test for string contains, use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with the appropriate patterns.

We can then use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to allow mapping of pattern to colour. Lastly, we can take advantage of the `subset` parameter of [`Styler.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) to only style specific columns instead of having to check the name of each column passed in:

```
def color_col(col):
    return np.select(
        [col.str.contains('TOR', na=False),
         col.str.contains('MTL', na=False),
         col.str.contains('VAN', na=False)],
        ['background-color: blue',
         'background-color: red',
         'background-color: green'],
        default=''
    ).astype(str)


df.style.apply(color_col, subset=['Visitor vs Home'])
```

We can also further parameterize our styling function so that we can pass a dictionary of patterns and corresponding colours instead:

```
def color_col(col, pattern_map, default=''):
    return np.select(
        [col.str.contains(k, na=False) for k in pattern_map.keys()],
        [f'background-color: {v}' for v in pattern_map.values()],
        default=default
    ).astype(str)


df.style.apply(color_col,
               pattern_map={'TOR': 'blue',
                            'MTL': 'red',
                            'VAN': 'green'},
               subset=['Visitor vs Home'])
```

Both options produce:

[image: styled table]

---

Sample Data and imports:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Visitor': ['TOR', 'MTL', 'VAN', 'WPG', 'EDM'],
    'Home': ['CGY', 'WPG', 'OTT', 'TOR', 'MTL'],
    'Visitor vs Home': ['String with TOR',
                        'String with MTL',
                        'String with VAN',
                        'String with no match',
                        np.NaN]
})
```

Comment: hmm I tried both options but neither of them worked for me. I don't get any errors, it still just exports with no colours

Comment: What exports with no colours? How are you exporting? You've saved an instance of the styler to use to export? Or you added your export to the derivative styles? [Example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749678/15497888)

Comment: Exporting to an html file

Comment: I understand. How are you exporting? You did in 2 steps `styler = df.style.apply(...)` `styler.to_html()` or added to the end of the styler `df.style.apply(...).to_html()`?

Comment: ah ok I got it to work by adding styler = df.style.apply(...) although it made the html table lose all its borders hahah. I will continue to look for solutions. Thank you for your help!