# Program to create multiple pivot tables in one excel worksheet

Tags: python, excel, sas, pivot-table

I need to create multiple pivot tables all put in on one worksheet, where the source data are the same and are stored in an external Excel workbook/file.  Is there a way to use programming/coding to accomplish this goal instead of manually inserting every pivot table one at a time?  The pivot tables will also be periodically updated based on the data updated/entered in the external source Excel file/workbook.

I know that SAS has `tagset.tableeditor` but my question for using this strategy  is:

1. does it support that data source file being an external excel file? I see that example codes always have a `proc print` procedure inside of the `ods`. Can I create all the pivot tables like this, and change the data source in connection button in Excel?
2. what is code to put the pivot table at a specific location in Excel?

what other programming languages are the best fit for this task? Python? R? Not entirely opposed to VBA if it is really the best to handle it.

Comment: It's certainly not an R question and if it were it would be an off-topic Q by virtue of being a a request for a recommendation for program.

Comment: If VBA is an option you can record a macro while creating a couple of pivot tables, then use that as a starting point

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a pivot table in Excel with python win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509367/how-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-excel-with-python-win32com)

Comment: I usually recommend creating the Excel files manually if it's a one time job and then updating the source and automating the refresh stage. This is infinitely faster. If you're programming, and using SAS, just use PROC TABULATE and pipe all your tables to workbooks. Do they have to Excel 'pivot' tables or just specific cross tabulations?

Comment: @Reeza I need to create a sort of tool kit, that users can update data in one workbook, and press "refresh" in another workbook to create pivot tables. The file with pivot tables is the one that ultimately is allowed to be shared. So yes, the user only uses Excel, and cannot do Excel call SAS something like that. There are lots of pivot tables, and yes, it is a one time job.  In essence, yes they are only cross-tabulations, but the "refresh" data part is repeated.

Comment: Do not change the data source. Replace it instead and then the only thing they need to do is to hit refresh. So your process should archive the old version first and then replace it with a new version if you need history.