# Pandas Excel Merge Cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, xlsxwriter

I'm trying to write a dataframe to excel, however I want the columns to span across two.
I have looked into XSLXWriter merge_range function however, I was unable to get it working with my pandas dataframe successfully.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['a'] = [1,2,3]
df['b'] = [3,4,5]
```

So I want my column, a, to span across B1 to C1 and my column b to span across D1 to E1

[image: Desired output]

Regarding XLSXWriter, I was able to use merge_range, however it was convoluded as I had to make an empty column in-between all columns to then merge. And as it overlaps "data", when opening the excel it would prompt with an error message saying the data might be corrupted.

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62509367/7758804) does not directly answer your question. However, it demonstrates how to use the python `win32com` package to access all Excel methods, which may be required to achieve your desired result.

Comment: please paste your code where you are using merge_range