# Python - Create Excel Pivot Table and add data to Data Model to enable Distinct Count functionality

Tags: python, excel, pivot-table

I'm new to python and am using it to automate the writing of an Excel file with pivot tables.

I've spent a while looking into this and am using win32com and pandas numpy, basing most of the Excel writing on Trenton McKinney's work:
[How to create a pivot table in Excel with python win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62509367/how-to-create-a-pivot-table-in-excel-with-python-win32com/62509368#62509368)

I'm creating the Excel with the Pivot table successfully and am really pleased I've got this far following the above.

The thing I'm stuck at is I need to add the data to the Data Model when creating the pivot table in Excel for two reasons:

1. I'll be creating numerous pivot tables from the data
2. most importantly to me, I need to use the Distinct Count capability this gives

I know there are other ways of creating the Distinct Count, but I'm part of a team that is more familiar with Excel and pivot tables, so I want to do it in Excel so that others can use the resultant Excel files.

I've tried recording the Macro as suggested, but can't see what flags make a difference.

I'm assuming this is the code that needs to change, but I can't find out how:

```
# grab the pivot table source data
pc = wb.PivotCaches().Create(SourceType=win32c.xlDatabase, SourceData=ws1.UsedRange)
# create the pivot table object
pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination=f'{ws_name}!R{pt_loc}C1', TableName=pt_name)
```